# Underfull and overfull \hbox in table

Tags: tables

Im really new to latex and have been using Excel2Latex to make tables, but I keep getting overfull and underfull errors, along with a single undefined control sequence. I would also really like to use \cite{} in the table fields, but no matter what I do I keep getting errors. How can I fix this issue if it comes up multiple times so I don't keep running into the same errors?
This is the table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{11.715em}|p{11.715em}|p{11.715em}|}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Express.js/Node.js }} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{ASP.NET Core}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Flask (Python)}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textit{Learning curve} & Prior knowledge with technology.Very lightweight, can be picked up quickly with existing JavaScript knowledge. & Prior knowledge with technology. Not lightweight.  & Some prior knowledge with Python. Flexible micro framework and easy to learn. \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textit{Supportability} & Extensive community, open source project, easy to get support. Uses JavaScript which is one of the most popular languages. & Created by Microsoft, detailed documentation, popular language  & Popular framework using python which is a popular language , with diverse forums and chat groups to get help.  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textit{License Cost} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Open Source.} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Open Source.} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{BSD License (free).} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textit{Scalability} & Good scalability, can be integrated with containers.  & Highly scalable, often used in enterprise solutions. & Flask alone does not scale well, but requires middleware and or libraries before being able to scale well. \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textit{File Structure} & Free folder/File structure & Standardized MVC folder structure. & Free structure, but proposes a layout in tutorial. \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:serveranalysis}%
  \caption{Server-Side Analysis}
\end{table}%
```

[image: Undefined control sequence here]

[image: Overfull here]

[image: underfull here]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are your document class  and its options?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following redesign based on `tabularx` and `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\itshape}p{2.2cm}LLL}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Express.js/Node.js }} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ASP.NET Core}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Flask (Python)}} \\
    \midrule
    Learning curve & Prior knowledge with technology.Very lightweight, can be picked up quickly with existing JavaScript knowledge. & Prior knowledge with technology. Not lightweight.  & Some prior knowledge with Python. Flexible micro framework and easy to learn. \\
    \textit{Supportability} & Extensive community, open source project, easy to get support. Uses JavaScript which is one of the most popular languages. & Created by Microsoft, detailed documentation, popular language  & Popular framework using python which is a popular language , with diverse forums and chat groups to get help.  \\
    License Cost & Open Source. & Open Source. & BSD License (free). \\
    Scalability & Good scalability, can be integrated with containers.  & Highly scalable, often used in enterprise solutions. & Flask alone does not scale well, but requires middleware and or libraries before being able to scale well. \\
    File Structure & Free folder/File structure & Standardized MVC folder structure. & Free structure, but proposes a layout in tutorial. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:serveranalysis}%
  \caption{Server-Side Analysis}
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overfull and underfull hboxes are unavoidable if you put text into narrow columns and require the text to be left- and right-justified. They are just warnings, and it is up to you to decide whether you have to care about some warnings because the output is too ugly or exceeds the page width.

As the page width is usually fixed, here are two possibilities to cope with too little space. The first one uses a smaller font, the second one turns the table sideways.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  {\footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{2cm}XXX@{}}
    \toprule
          & \textbf{Express.js/Node.js} & \textbf{ASP.NET Core} & \textbf{Flask (Python)}\\
    \midrule
    \textit{Learning curve} & Prior knowledge with technology.Very lightweight, can be picked up quickly with existing JavaScript knowledge. & Prior knowledge with technology. Not lightweight.  & Some prior knowledge with Python. Flexible micro framework and easy to learn.\\
    \midrule
    \textit{Supportability} & Extensive community, open source project, easy to get support. Uses JavaScript which is one of the most popular languages. & Created by Microsoft, detailed documentation, popular language  & Popular framework using python which is a popular language , with diverse forums and chat groups to get help.  \\
    \midrule
    \textit{License Cost} & Open Source & Open Source & BSD License (free) \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Scalability} & Good scalability, can be integrated with containers.  & Highly scalable, often used in enterprise solutions. & Flask alone does not scale well, but requires middleware and or libraries before being able to scale well. \\
    \midrule
    \textit{File Structure} & Free folder/File structure & Standardized MVC folder structure. & Free structure, but proposes a layout in tutorial. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}%
  }
  \caption{Server-Side Analysis}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cXXX@{}}
    \toprule
          & \textbf{Express.js/Node.js} & \textbf{ASP.NET Core} & \textbf{Flask (Python)}\\
    \midrule
    \textit{Learning curve} & Prior knowledge with technology.Very lightweight, can be picked up quickly with existing JavaScript knowledge. & Prior knowledge with technology. Not lightweight.  & Some prior knowledge with Python. Flexible micro framework and easy to learn.\\
    \midrule
    \textit{Supportability} & Extensive community, open source project, easy to get support. Uses JavaScript which is one of the most popular languages. & Created by Microsoft, detailed documentation, popular language  & Popular framework using python which is a popular language , with diverse forums and chat groups to get help.  \\
    \midrule
    \textit{License Cost} & Open Source & Open Source & BSD License (free) \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Scalability} & Good scalability, can be integrated with containers.  & Highly scalable, often used in enterprise solutions. & Flask alone does not scale well, but requires middleware and or libraries before being able to scale well. \\
    \midrule
    \textit{File Structure} & Free folder/File structure & Standardized MVC folder structure. & Free structure, but proposes a layout in tutorial. \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Server-Side Analysis}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does this part do? {@{}p{2cm}XXX@{}}

Comment: `@{}` replaces the intercolumn space by whatever appears between the braces, here: nothing. It thus removes the extra space to the left and right. `p{2cm}` means a column of width `2cm`, where text is typeset justified on both sides (normal paragraph mode). The three `X` column divide the sremaining space left by the other columns equally among each other, typesetting also in paragraph mode.